# Return a set of all of the words in the word list that can be made with subset of input characters

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on below problem but not able to figure out how to approach this problem in Java?

> Given an array of characters, returns a Set of all of the words in the
>   word list that can be made with any subset of those characters.
>   Duplicates may be present in the array, but each array index may only
>   be used once per word. Thus, given {'o', 'r', 's', 'd', 'o', 'w', 'e'}
>   you might return (among others) "word", "words", and "wood", but not
>   "order".

```
class Finder {

  public void init(Set<String> words) {

  }

  public Set<String> find(List<Character> chars) {

  }
}
```

What should be the idea to approach this kind of problem?

Comment: You'll want to assign the `words` set to an instance variable of `Finder` (you'll need to make it before you can assign it). In the `find` method you'll then need to compare each word in the `words` instance variable to the `chars` parameter, and see if it can be created. Fill up a new set with each valid word. You'll need loops, and I'd encourage you to look up something called a frequency map.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am mainly confuse on this `In the find method you'll then need to compare each word in the words instance variable to the chars parameter, and see if it can be created`. Let me think more on this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one of possible approaches:

1. make a count array/map/hashtable to count how much of each character you have,
   so in example you gave it would be `cnt['o']=2, cnt['r']=1, cnt['s']=1` and so on
2. Loop through all words and for each word create another count array structure, lets name it `cnt2`
3. Word can be made only if `cnt[x] >= cnt2[x]` for all distinct letters of a word
4. Collect all words satisfying this property and put them into set

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, by using the `Collection.remove(Object o)` that returns a boolean:

```
private static boolean canBeDoneWith(String word, List<Character> chars) {
    List<Character> temp = new ArrayList<>(chars);
    for (char c: word.toCharArray()) {
        if (!temp.remove(Character.valueOf(c))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Method `find` becomes:

```
public Set<String> find(List<Character> chars) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (String word: words) {
        if (canBeDoneWith(word, chars)) {
            result.add(word);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```