# How to implement an efficient WordFinder?

Tags: python, java, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked the following question in an interview.

```
class WordFinder:
    def init(words):
    def find(characters):
```

> Given the class above (pseudocode, fit it to language of your choice), where `words` is a set of words use to initialize the class, and `characters` is a list of characters, return all the words from `words` that can be formed by any subset of `characters`. You may do some preprocessing if needed.
>
> Example:
>
> words = { "wood", "word", "words" }
>
> characters = [ 'o', 'w', 'o', 's', 'd', 'a', 'r' ]
>
> Output: { "wood", "word", "words" }

Which I implemented in Python as follows:

```
from typing import Set, Sequence
import collections

class WordFinder:
    def __init__(self, words: Set[str]):
        self._words = { word: collections.Counter(word) for word in words }

    def find(self, characters: Sequence[str]) -> Sequence[str]:
        x = collections.Counter(characters)
        return [word for word, c in self._words.items() if not (c - x)]

words = {"wood", "word", "words"}
wf = WordFinder(words)
actual = wf.find(['o', 'w', 'o', 's', 'd', 'a', 'r'])
assert set(actual) == words
```

This works, but the `find` method loops over all the words each time. Is there a better way? The statement that some preprocessing can be done seems to be a hint that I didn't take.

Python or Java implementation are acceptable.

> Disclaimer: I found that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56641279/839733) had been asked before, but no answer was accepted, and none of the answers are better than what I did.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might better site for this question.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam My question isn't a code review, is it?

Comment: Your code works and you want to improve it, aren't you? I think it will be better suited in codereview.stackexchange.com (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) . That's my opinion.

Comment: Use of regular expression on finding pattern may help

Comment: @HetalThaker What regex and what pattern? Show an example.

Comment: The preprocessing could be used to [build a trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). I would expect that to be faster if  A) you don't count the preprocessing time, and B) the number of words is large, and C) the number of characters is small.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yes, I can post a code that I tried, but it does not follow OOP structure as given in the problem. The only core logic is implemented.

Comment: temp = "".join(characters)

Comment: m = re.compile('^['+temp+']+$')

Comment: print([word for word in words if m.match(word) is not None])

Comment: btw: you *did* do some preprocessing by pre-counting the letters in every word in the `words` list.

Comment: @user3386109 I did, usually preprocessing strings leads to a better runtime than linear time, so I’m scratching my head here.

Comment: Yup, if N is the number of words in the `words` list, and M is the number of words in the output list, the best you can do is O(M). In the example, M and N are the same, so there's no way to beat linear time. And that's why in my first comment I mentioned the constraint: *"C) the number of characters is small"*. If the character set is sufficient to make every word in the dictionary, then you can't do better than O(N) because the output size is O(N).

Comment: Which is to say that I think your answer is correct (unless they put some constraints on the problem that weren't mentioned here).

Answer (score 2):

Trie implementation in java. This avoids scan over the entire wordlist, so its complexity is limited to char length.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WordFinder {
class TrieNode {
    boolean isEnd;
    TrieNode[] children;
    String word;

    TrieNode() {
        isEnd = false;
        children = new TrieNode[26];
    }
}

TrieNode root;

public void init(String[] words) {
    root = new TrieNode();
    for (String w : words) {
        insert(w);
    }
}

private void insert(String w) {
    TrieNode curr = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); ++i) {
        char c = w.charAt(i);

        if (curr.children[c - 'a'] == null)
            curr.children[c - 'a'] = new TrieNode();

        curr = curr.children[c - 'a'];
    }

    curr.isEnd = true;
    curr.word=w;
}


public String[] find(char[] chars) {

    Map<Character, Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
        char c = chars[i];
        mp.put(c, mp.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }
    Set<String> set  = new HashSet<>();
    dfs(root, mp, 0,set);
    return set.toArray(new String[0]);
}

private void dfs(TrieNode curr, Map<Character, Integer> mp, int l,Set<String> set) {
    //base
    if (curr.isEnd) {
        set.add(curr.word);
    }

    //logic
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        char c = (char) (i + 'a');

        if (curr.children[i] != null) {
            if (mp.containsKey(c) && mp.get(c) > 0) {
                mp.put(c, mp.get(c) - 1);
                dfs(curr.children[i], mp, l + 1,set);
                mp.put(c, mp.get(c) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    WordFinder wordFinder=new WordFinder();
    String[] words = { "wood", "word", "words" };
    char[] chars={ 'o', 'w', 'o', 's', 'd', 'a', 'r' };
    wordFinder.init(words);
    String[] res = wordFinder.find(chars);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));

}
```

}

output:
[words, wood, word]

Comment: This seems like a good idea because you avoid going down the branches with characters not in the map, but not without problems, the biggest of which is that you provided no explanation whatsoever, and just dumped some code on us. Also, in the worst case, this implementation is significantly more involved with no better time complexity than the one in my question. See my answer for a time complexity analysis.

Comment: True, the worst case will not be reduced for proper prefix dictionary, thanks for pointing out. Some custom compressed trie may work, for slightly better performance.

Comment: I was wrong about the prefix example. Actually, with prefixes, you only need to traverse the longest prefix. I've corrected my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

`"word"` is a substring/subset of `"words"`, so you could do some preprocessing to detect those, and build a tree from that, i.e. attach `"words"` as a child of `"word"` (because it needs one additional letter `'s'`). When checking for a match, if `"word"` already failed, you do not need to traverse the rest of the tree of supersets downwards anymore. The initial initialization will be slower due to preprocessing, but the `find` should be faster. I assume that `find` is ought be be called a lot of times, but initialization only once.

I cannot produce the pseudocode for that right now, but I guess the idea might be sufficient for you to do it.

Comment: This seems like quite a bit of hand waving with nothing concrete.

Answer (score 0):

OP here; here's a Python implementation inspired by ryuik's answer using a Trie. The idea is to do a DFS for each child in the Trie node that corresponds to a character not yet used. Then we backtrack.

```
class WordFinder:
    def __init__(self, *words):
        self.__children: MutableMapping[str, WordFinder] = dict()
        self.__end: bool = False
        for word in words:
            self.put(word)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.__children.keys()})"

    def put(self, word: str):
        self.__put(word, 0)

    def __put(self, word: str, i: int):
        if i == len(word):
            self.__end = True
        else:
            ch = word[i]
            if ch not in self.__children:
                self.__children[ch] = WordFinder()
            self.__children[ch].__put(word, i + 1)

    def find(self, chars: Sequence[str]) -> Set[str]:
        words = set()
        self.__find(collections.Counter(chars), [], words)
        return words

    def __find(self, chars: MutableMapping[str, int], prefix: MutableSequence[str], words: MutableSet[str]):
        if self.__end:
            words.add("".join(prefix))
        for ch in [k for k, v in chars.items() if v > 0 and k in self.__children]:
            chars[ch] -= 1
            prefix.append(ch)
            self.__children[ch].__find(chars, prefix, words)
            prefix.pop()
            chars[ch] += 1
```

**Time complexity:** If average word length is `k`, and there are `n` words, we do `O(nk)` word for `init` and `find`.

Example: words = { "aa", "bb", "cc" }, characters = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"].

In the worst case, this implementation is significantly more involved with no better time complexity than the one in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Any optimization has prerequisites. For the test cases you give now, you have done well enough. But you want to reduce the number of loops, then I assume that each of your words has millions of characters, then you can use `buckets` to optimize

```java
public class Test21 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test21 ts = new Test21();
        int[] src = ts.find(new char[]{'o', 'w', 'o', 's', 'd', 'a', 'r'});
        ts.init(new String[]{"wood", "word", "words", "wooood", "w"}, src);
    }
    
    public int[] find(char[] by){
        int[] src = new int[26];
        for(int i: by){
            src[i - 97] = src[i - 97] + 1; 
        }
        return src;
    }
    
    public void init(String[] tar, int[] src){
        for(String str: tar){
            if(this.compare(this.find(str.toCharArray()), src))
                System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    
    private boolean compare(int[] tar, int[] src){
        for(int i = 0; i < src.length; i++){
            if(tar[i] > src[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `init` is a language-specific constructor, as mentioned in the problem statement "_`words` is a set of words use to initialize the class_". In Java, it's the class name, in Python it's the `__init__` function. You can't call `init` as a method after instantiating the class.